# can an object be outside the VP in the X-Bar theory?

Tags: x-bar-theory, verb-phrase

everyone. I'm reading an article, and something makes me confused.

In the article there is a sample sentence: (5) Mary hates sharks.

Diesing claims that the object in (5) occupies a VP-external position at
LF; it has been scrambled into a position dominated by IP.

I am quite confused that how could the object occupy a VP-external position at LF? where should the object be put at LF? I think objects are always at VP-internal position like [image]

Comment: Which article is this? I would also expect the object in a simple sentence like "Mary hates sharks" to be inside the VP.